# Use single psi(tomcat) probe to monitor multiple instances across different tomcat instances

Tags: tomcat, multiple-instances, probe

I have multiple applications running on different ports (`tomcat instances`)

All have the same `CATALINA_HOME`

Currently I have to deploy and install **psi probe** in all the instances and separately monitor each port in different window.

How can I monitor all the applications(across all instances) in one single probe interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. PSI probe has to be deployed in the Tomcat instance it is monitoring. There are monitoring solutions for multiple Tomcat instances but at a minimum they will require an agent to be installed on the instance being monitored.

Comment: Thank you Mark, can you provide a few option that allow monitoring multiple tomcat instances...

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial and free solutions for this. We use ManageCat enterprise monitoring platform which allows to manage and monitor all deployed applications and servers from a single location. They also provide free agents. Check out their web site, http://managecat.com for more information. It uses agent based solution.

As an open source free alternative, you can also checkout Apache Sirona http://sirona.incubator.apache.org/